# how to add menu at front

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i am using menu control in asp.net and i am having already 4 menu items, but i want to add 3 more menu items at front.how to achieve this ?

```
<asp:Menu ID="MainMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" 
     CssClass="styleMenu"       Width="100%" >
     <Items>                                        
         <asp:MenuItem Text="Approval" Value="3"></asp:MenuItem>
         <asp:MenuItem Text="Search" Value="4"></asp:MenuItem>
         <asp:MenuItem Text="Admin" Value="5"></asp:MenuItem>
         <asp:MenuItem Text="Report" Value="6"></asp:MenuItem> 
     </Items>
 </asp:Menu>
```

I am writing the code for adding dynamic menu items as

```
MenuItem mnuTest = new MenuItem();
mnuTest.NavigateUrl = "";
mnuTest.Text = "Test";
MainMenu.Items.Add(mnuTest);
```

but the latest menu is adding at last , how to add at front as 1st menu item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MainMenu.Items.AddAt(0, mnuTest);
```